# Chromium can't save files to home subfolders

Tags: permissions, snap, chromium, 22.04, apparmor

I experience a blocking problem : `Chromium` (snap install), `Chrome` (deb package), `Firefox` (ubuntu's pre-installed) and `Telegram` (snap) can't save files to custom subfolders in home directory.

Ex. Chromium can download any file to `/home/user/`, `/home/user/Desktop/` but not in `/home/user/test/`.

It's a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a new laptop, with a single user (eg. `user`).
The owner and group of the folders are well set to the owner of the home directory. Permissions are set to 755 on folders.
`/home` is on a separate partition handled by LVM, the whole system runs on a single disk.
`SElinux` is not installed. Gnome is running with Xorg. Nothing fancy.

I experimented with this weird behavior and noticed that I could not save files from those apps into a folder that I copied from my previous laptop (eg. `/home/user/old_data/`). As the permissions were `775` I changed it to `755` which allowed to save files in it, but not in its subfolders (eg. `/home/user/old_data/test/`). I could not reproduce with other folders that I created in $HOME.

Other applications like `gedit` can save files in those folders without problems, even `Pycharm` (snap) can operate on `/home/user/old_data/*` without problems.

I thought that it could come from `apparmor`, so I tried to disable it (`sudo systemctl disable apparmor` and reboot). It prevented `snap` based apps from starting, and it didn't solve the problem for `Chrome`.

Right now I'm stuck, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Snaps run *confined* and have permissions to write anywhere on home (*but cannot follow a link in $HOME to a different volume thus a different drive*) or you can enable them to save to `/mnt` and `/media` as well. This is a security '*feature*' and even if permissions are RW they cannot break *confinement* to get there. Is this your issue?

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for the pointer but there's no link, just plain files and directories. $HOME is a true sub folder of `/home`, sitting on the same partition, without hard or symbolic links. Also I checked that applications have `snap` connection `home`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the permissions. It looks that after changing them (chmod g+w) and (opening a new tab? restarting the browser?) the snap Firefox can save the files.